# Why is diluting eps wrong?

Tags: earnings

During my studies, all I hear is managers/directors try to avoid diluting eps. I do not see why this would be a problem as a simple stock split would dilute eps without having any effect on the operations

Similarly, an increase in eps as a result of share buyback is completely irrelevant in my view.

Is there any ground for the fear of diluting eps?

Comment: Many people have a mental model where the price of the stock is equal to K times EPS, where K is some kind of constant for a given type of firm. Obviously this is a rather simplistic model of stock valuation that leads to many fallacies and Finance courses explain why this is so (at least I hope they do). But an operating manager who does not handle finance probably does not take such a course.

Comment: Accounting professor Stephen Penman calls this bias "functional fixedness" with respect to earnings.  https://books.google.com/books?id=5A8fY-RKZLIC&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194#v=onepage&q&f=false